# jQuery focusin event: Why is event.data empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focus

My binder:

```
$("#wrapper").on("focusin", ".someInputField", function(e, a) {
    /* do something */
});
```

My trigger:

```
$('.someInputField').trigger("focus", ["extra", "data"]);
```

How do I get to the "extra" and "data" values? `e.data` and `a` are always undefined. (Firefox 18)

However related question: Is there a possibility to distinguish between
a) The inputField got focus by tabbing or clicking
b) The inputField got focus by some .trigger() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order you trigger your event is important here:

```
$('input').on('focusin', function(event, extra, data) {
    console.log(extra, data);
});
$('input').trigger('focusin', ['extra', 'data']);
```

**[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rvX5Y/)**

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, that SHOULD work, however in the console it says 'undefined undefined'. Try it!

Comment: Works in the fiddle, doesn't work in my project. :/ Thank you, I'll give it some more tries.

Comment: @Heiko Ok! Is your question answered for now? Then mark it as it is!

Comment: We may have stumbled upon a bug in jQuery 1.9.0. Works perfectly fine in jQuery 1.8.3, but not in the newer version. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Heiko No, i cannot! Works fine, even with 1.7.2: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rvX5Y/5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of `trigger` extra parameters usage : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/10/

About your second question, if you add an extra parameter when you are using the `trigger` function, you can test if it is a native event or not. In the following example, if `param1` and `param2` are NOT `null`, the event has been called from the `trigger` function :

```
$("#wrapper").on("focus", ".someInputField", function(e, param1, param2) {
    /* do something */
    param1 = param1 || null;
    param2 = param2 || null;

    //param 1 and param2 are not null if the event has been called from trigger function
    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);   
});

$('.someInputField').trigger("focus", ["data","test"]);
```